# If a cell is empty go to next line in code

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA script executes the steps, say **A-E**.
I would like if the last field of **E2 contains nothing**, then only **execute A-D**.

The **same for D2. If this cell has no content then only A-C** and so on until **A-B** since these are never empty.

Below is an extract of the script so far for every possibility.

```vb
Sub Variations()

Dim rngAList, rngBList, rngCList, rngDList, rngEList As Range
Dim rngA, rngB, rngC, rngD, rngE As Range
Dim strVariationList As String

Set rngAList= Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Range("B2"), Tabelle3.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
Set rngBList= Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Range("D2"), Tabelle3.Range("D2").End(xlDown))
Set rngCList= Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Range("F2"), Tabelle3.Range("F2").End(xlDown))
Set rngDList= Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Range("G2"), Tabelle3.Range("G2").End(xlDown))
Set rngEList= Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Range("H2"), Tabelle3.Range("H2").End(xlDown))

Tabelle3.Range("I2").Select

For Each rngA In rngAList
    For Each rngB In rngBList
        For Each rngC In rngCList
            For Each rngD In rngDList
                For Each rngE In rngEList
                
                    ActiveCell = "" & rngA.Value & " " & rngB & " " & rngC & " " & rngD & " " & rngE
                
                    If strVariationList = "" Then
                        strVariationList = ActiveCell
                    Else
                        strVariationList = strVariationList & ", " & ActiveCell
                    End If
                        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next

Tabelle3.Range("J2").Select

For Each rngA In rngAList
    For Each rngB In rngBList
        For Each rngC In rngCList
            For Each rngD In rngDList
                
                    ActiveCell = "" & rngA.Value & " " & rngB & " " & rngC & " " & rngD
                
                    If strVariationList = "" Then
                        strVariationList = ActiveCell
                    Else
                        strVariationList = strVariationList & ", " & ActiveCell
                    End If
                        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: You can use Exit For to terminate a loop prematurely, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Use an if statement to check if the cell is empty, then use Exit For to leave the loop if the cell is found to be empty.

Comment: First of all thank you for the fast feedback!
It's a permutation tool that im trying to build with variable input, like i said if column cell X is empty permute columns 1-4 if column 4 is empty permute just column 1-3 and so on :)

Comment: how many cells are in your source ranges? This must take forever to run! Also, why do it twice? Why not just set Column `J` equal to Column `I`?

Comment: 1. Find the last used cell/row and assign that to LastCell. 2. For i = 1 to LastCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I recommend to use:

```
Dim testEmpty As String 
'before reading cell value clear string
testEmpty = ""
If(IsEmpty(testEmpty) = true) Then
     GoTo OverStepCode
End If

' here code that executes when cell is not empty

OverStepCode:
' here code that executes always but You overstep code that should not be executed when cell is empty
```